# Query not attempting to insert into identity column but getting error : Cannot insert explicit ... identity column ... when Identity_Insert is off

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008

I am simply attempting to insert a new record into our SQL Server database. The insert is happening from within a WCF web service using LINQ.

The table d_coord_report_conflict is structured as follows:

```
conflict_report_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
booking_id int,
conflict_date date,
coord_user_id int
guide_one_user_id int,
guide_two_user_id int,
product_id int,
price_id int
```

Everything is a foreign key except conflict_report_id and conflict_date.
Here's the insert from the WCF service in C#:

```
d_coord_report_conflict conflict = new d_coord_report_conflict
{
         booking_id = bookingID,
         conflict_date = date,
         coord_user_id = Convert.ToInt32(item.coordID),
         guide_one_user_id = pax.user_id_guide,
         guide_two_user_id = Convert.ToInt32(item.guideID),
         product_id = Convert.ToInt32(item.productID),
         price_id = Convert.ToInt32(item.priceID)
};

db.d_coord_report_conflicts.InsertOnSubmit(conflict);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

It should be a straight forward insert but it keeps throwing back the following error:

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'd_coord_report_conflict'        when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

As far as I can see this shouldn't be happening. Also, turning on IDENTITY_INSERT is not an acceptable solution as I'm sure you understand.

**UPDATE:** I recovered the values of each field is it is passed into the LINQ query and attempted a manual insert from within SQL Server Management Studio and it worked fine. no errors at all. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637121/linq-to-sql-why-am-i-getting-identity-insert-errors

Answer (score 0):

What query have u written in method db.d_coord_report_conflicts.InsertOnSubmit(conflict)?
Whether it is stored proc, or an inline sql query in c#, check for correct column names and order. 
remember: you must not pass value/mention name of identity column in INSERT query.

if your table is like this

```
Create table Test 
{   
     testId int not null identity primary key,   
     testName varchar(50),   createdDate datetime 
}
```

Your INSERT query should be something like

```
INSERT INTO TEST(testName,createdDate) values ('New Test', getdate())
```

observe that i have not mentioned the identity column anywhere in the insert query, since its value is automatically filled
Hope this makes sense!